# When linear differential equation can also directly be solved by variable separable method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x).$ 
1. What conditions may  be imposed on functions $p(x)$ and/or $q(x)$ so that it could directly be solved by variable separable method rather than integrating factor $e^{\int p(x) dx}$. 
2. In the case if it can be solved by both variable separable and integrating factor method, which would be more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the general linear ODE and the separable linear ODE,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x) y = q(x) \quad \textrm{and} \quad \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) (ay+b),
\end{equation}
we note that the linear ODE is separable if and only if
\begin{equation}
q(x) - p(x)y = f(x) (ay+b),
\end{equation}
with a new function $f$. This is the case if $q(x) = c p(x)$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$, since then we obtain $q(x) - p(x) y = p(x)(c-y)$.

The solution of a separable linear ODE
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x) y = c p(x) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{dy}{dx} = p(x)(c-y)
\end{equation}
via separation of variables or via an integrating factor is a matter of preference, and with both methods we obtain the general solution
\begin{equation}
y(x) = c + C e^{-P(x)}, \quad C \in \mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
where $P$ is an antiderivative of $p$.